# What is the easiest way to put a responsive logo into a Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I am a noob, working through using this template : http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/freelancer/

I am editing it, and trying to get some bells and whistles to work better. I want to put my logo into the header and have it be responsive, I cannot get other answers I've found here to work... I may be a bit thick, in fact that is probably the big issue.

What is the easiest way to place a responsive logo graphic into the bootstrap navbar?

This is the code I currently have.

```
</head>

<body id="page-top" class="index">

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <a href="#" class="pull-left"><img src="images/My_logo_navbar.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
      <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
</div>
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
<div class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-left"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/My_logo_navbar.png"></a></div>
```

after the `</button>`

In this way boostrap automatically position your logo on left top corner.

And crop your `My_logo_navbar.png` to size you want and use media queries to change it width or height on smaller devices. If you want you can use two of `navbar-brand` classes with separate id's. One for larger screens and one for smaller screens.
I always use this for my projects.

Comment: Thank you Sasith, what would the code look like for the media query? I can't stress enough my noobiness in bootstrap.

Comment: Add "mobile-logo" as id to mobile logo and "desktop-logo" as id to desktop logo and Add  #mobile-logo{display:none;} and then add " @media and (max-width: 767px) { #desktop-logo{display:none;}  #mobile-logo{display:block;} } " to your css.